# how to create n number of matrixs

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

i dont use python however im trying to run a code for matrices, is it possible to create n number of matrices based on the user input?
The user will input number of rows for example 3 , so i need to generate 3 matrices

this is what i have however i created the matrices manually

```
  
R = int(input("Enter the number of rows:"))
C = R+1
  
  
print("Enter the entries in a single line (separated by space): ")
  
# User input of entries in a 
# single line separated by space
entries = list(map(int, input().split()))
  
# For printing the matrix
matrix = np.array(entries).reshape(R, C)
print(matrix)

de = matrix[:,0:R]
print(de)

    
de0 = np.copy(de)
de0[:,0] = matrix[:,R]
de1 = np.copy(de)
de1[:,1] = matrix[:,R]
de2 = np.copy(de)
de2[:,2] = matrix[:,R]
```

here i made de0,de1,de2 assuming user input was 3, but if it was 10 so i need de0,de1...de9 so it is possible to create them automatically based on the user input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you need to create variable names dynamically. Use globals()

```py
# This is going to create 10 variables de0, de1,.., de9 and assign None to those
for ind in range(10):
    globals()[f'de{ind}'] = None # Replace None with whatever you need to assign
```

Comment: thank you that worked, however how do u access the matrix again ? if i need to do something like in my previous example de0[:,0] = matrix[:,R] but within the loop, i tried this 
```globals()[f'de{ind}[:,ind]'] = matrix[:,R]``` but nothing changed in the matrix

Comment: How about `(globals()[f'de{ind}'])[:, ind] = matrix[:,R]`. See that I have brought the indexer out of the string. `globals()[f'de{ind}']` is going to give you the dataframe and on top of that you do whatever operation you'd like to do